# Troubleshooting LAN transfer between a Windows PC and a Raspberry Pi using iPerf

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, iperf

I am trying to transfer GoPro files from my desktop Windows PC to a Raspberry Pi media server. Ive been using WinSCP before, and it always worked great, but in the past 6 months or so, the transfer speeds seem to have been totally throttled.

When I start a transfer now, it will initially start out around 4 MB/S, then drop successively down to ~200-300 kb/s in a roughly 15-second time frame. I have the rPi and PC both hooked into a network switch via CAT6 cables.

I tried running iPerf between the two machines, and the results look a little odd. On my PC, it looks like nothing is getting sent to the Raspberry Pi, but on the Raspberry Pi side, it says it is both sending/receiving? Obviously I am not interpreting this right, how can I troubleshooting this?

I tried this both for TCP and UDP connections, and things look off. I will post the TCP connection screenshots first, followed by the UDP:

**PC TCP**:

[image: PC TCP]

**Raspberry Pi TCP**:

[image: Raspberry Pi TCP]

**PC TCP**:

[image: PC UDP]

**Raspberry Pi UDP**:

[image: Raspberry Pi UDP]